# Issues accessing school Google Account, after getting locked out of it

Tags: google-drive, google-account

I just graduated this May and essentially, I had to get as many important files transported from my school account to my main before June. I'd say I did a good job of doing that, but not necessarily good enough. There are a few files I had either forgotten, overlooked, or now realized I wanted them. I didn't transfer my whole drive as there were a bunch of assignments and projects.

Fortunately, I can access the see files on the Drive app (Android), as I never signed out. However, every 10 - 15 or so seconds, it generates a prompt to sign in, it's a weird state. I'm not signed out, but I'm supposed to be locked out. So although I'm technically in, Google wants to verify it's me. At this point, I can see what files I have, but I can't preview unfortunately, for the most part. It's a Google *purgatory*.

I can edit docs if I'm offline (meaning I can copy text, and paste to a new doc in my main acc.), but that's all. If I try opening a Spreadsheet, I'll end up having a "**Please make sure you are connect to the internet**" error. Can't download images, and downloading docs/sheets/slides download an unopenable pdf on Android. Not only that but, if I use the link to a file, it's an "Access Denied" page, and says "Can't access item. The organization that owns this item doesn't allow you to access it" on the page. Not even a request access button.

To top it all off, the sign in to google with my school google email, redirects to a page that is an **adfs** page. I won't reveal the exact link, but it's pretty much adfs.***.org. Can't sign in as I'm not enrolled. So I want to bypass the adfs, and just have to continue with a regular google sign in prompt, as you would a regular Google account, if it works out. And in general, I'd like to find a way bypass school restrictions and regain access to a few files.

Comment: Sounds to me like your school account doesn't exist anymore but the Drive app has not recognized that. Now you can do everything which works offline (e.g. cached documents) but as soon as you try to do something online it fails because the account does no longer exists or is disabled and thus online access if impossible. You can not bypass the sign-in dialog because your account does no longer exists and even if you would manage to bypass it you would recognize that your files no longer exist. It is only your Drive app which has not realized that...

Comment: I really want to see if those "cached documents" can be viewed in a google tab (so I can view on Desktop), instead just on the app. Also how come I can't view my Spreadsheet as a "cached doc", like I can with Slides/Docs. Is there a way I can? And is there a time limit before I can't access the files or account at all?

Comment: Plus I'd like save some as Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, but I doubt I could do that at this point :(